# #pragma interrupt for GCC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-flags

I'm new to embedded programming so I am not sure on the syntax. I need to make this available for the GCC toolchain. My driver was compiled using a different toolchain. I frankly haven't used compiler flags much at all so I'm a bit at a loss. This link gives the format I think I should be using: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html

I need to change the syntax of this line to match GCC:

```
#pragma interrupt int_cmt0_isr(vect=VECT(CMT0,CMI0))
```

I think it should look something like this:

```
void __attribute__ ((interrupt ("CMT0, CMI0"))) int_cmt0_isr ();
```

int_cmt0_isr() is a function that should be called when an iterrupt occurs at that location in the vectortable.

If you can help that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: That looks pretty close to what will work if you're compiling for a target where the option is supported.  It is not clear that you can specify two interrupts at once; you might need to write two separate attributes.  It is also not clear which platform supports CMT0 and CMI0, or you may need to convert those names to ones which GCC does support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add special entries into a separate interrupt table for the version of GCC that I was using for this device. I ended up not using the #pragma at all.